# Java issue with ImageIO compressing images

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am finishing up a java app that can compress multi-page tiff images. The issue is that this works perfectly fine inside of my IDE as well as in a local environment on the same computer if I run it as a .jar file, however if I try to run it on a different computer that also has java installed, it compresses the tiff files but those images are no longer viewable. Clicking on them brings up the "no preview available" for windows image viewer. What could be causing this? The specific method I use for compressing the multi-page tiffs is as follows:

```
public synchronized void compress() throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("NUMpAGES: " + numPages);
    if(this.getSrcImageFile().length()<SIZE_THRESHOLD){
        this.closeAllStreams();
        return;
    }
    this.initOutStreams();
    this.setImageEncoder(ImageCodec.createImageEncoder("tiff", this.getOutputStream(), null));
    int compressionAlgorithm;
    if(bitDepth == 1 || bitDepth == 8)
    {
        /*Cant use JPEG_TTN2 with images that have less than 8-bit samples/only have a bit-depth of 1.*/   
        compressionAlgorithm = TIFFEncodeParam.COMPRESSION_DEFLATE;
        encodeParams.setCompression(compressionAlgorithm); //redundant with line above
    }
    else
    {

        System.out.println("Attempting to compress using JPEG_TTN2 with bit depth: " + bitDepth);
        compressionAlgorithm = TIFFEncodeParam.COMPRESSION_JPEG_TTN2;
        encodeParams.setCompression(compressionAlgorithm); //redundant with line above
    }
    this.setImageEncoder(ImageCodec.createImageEncoder("tiff", this.getOutputStream(), encodeParams));
    Vector vector = new Vector();
    if(numPages == 1){
         for(int i = 0; i < numPages - 1; i ++) //i < bufferedImages.length OLD
         {
              System.out.println(i);
              vector.add((bufferedImages[i]));
         } 
    }else{
         System.out.println("Using second case");
         for(int i = 0; i < numPages; i ++)
         {
              System.out.println("Adding to vector image for file " + this.getSrcImagePath() + " " + i);
              vector.add((bufferedImages[i]));
         }            
    }

    System.out.println("Buffered Images size: " + bufferedImages.length);

    Iterator vecIter = vector.iterator();
    if(numPages > 1){
        vecIter.next();
    }

    encodeParams.setExtraImages(vecIter);
    this.getImageEncoder().encode(bufferedImages[0]);
    closeAllStreams();
}
```

Comment: Have those non-local installations a copy of ImageIO? JAI doesn't come with the JDK AFAIK.

Comment: First, check whether it really has to do with your code. Does the other computer show preview for other TIFF files, e.g. the ones that work on your computer? Does your computer show a preview for the images generated on the other computer?

Comment: @mabi: ImageIO obviously *is* installed in the other JRE, otherwise it wouldn’t produce any files.

Comment: @Holger The other computer shows a preview of the TIFF before I do anything with it. After my code runs it shows the "no preview available." On my main machine, it shows a tiff preview before AND afterwards. I have installed ImageIO for CLASSPATH and ImageIO for JRE on the other machine and there are no exceptions that are being thrown during runtime from the command prompt, so I am at a loss as to what could be causing this.

Comment: You should check what happens with the *processed* images. Do they really differ? As already said, check whether the second computer can preview an image *processed* by the first computer and vice versa.

Comment: @Holger Hmm, I transferred a processed image from my main computer (that can preview it) to the computer that cannot and it was NOT able to preview the image.

Comment: @mabi  I think your comment cuts directly to the cause of this problem.  See my answer for expansion.

Comment: @user1806716: then try the other direction, just to be sure. So it seems to be an issue with the environment. Either with the system software (i.e. Windows version) or installed third party software. Since you are changing the compression, there might be image import filters not capable of handling this compression.

Comment: @Holger So far I have tried both DEFLATE and JPEG TTN2 compression that both work on my main machine, but dont work on the other machine. Is there somewhere that I can download the proper supporting import filters? Also, if I go to the image properties, the output image never shows a compression type at all, shouldn't it show whichever one I chose in my code?

Comment: It’s very hard to diagnostic. And it’s not a Java question anymore…

Answer (score 0):

I will repeat something @mabi said in the first (and so far only good) comment

> JAI doesn't come with the JDK AFAIK.

I can upgrade that AFAIK to 'no'.  JAI is ***not*** supplied with the JRE.

Further the SPIs (Service Provider Interface) for processing TIFF come with JAI.  The JSE based portion of `ImageIO` uses the SPI to identify encoders & decoders for a file type.  I suspect that because JAI is not installed in the 2nd computer (or otherwise added to the run-time class-path of the app.) that is why it is failing.

As to why it does not obviously fail in your code, it is probably due to how the exceptions it throws are handled.  I suspect they are simply being ignored.

Comment: I have installed JAI ImageIO on both computers. As I was saying to @Holger , if I generated an image on the machine that works and simply transferred it to the machine that doesn't, I counld't preview the image anymore (and I COULD preview it on the main machine). I looked at the image properties and noticed that after generating the image, some off the properties were completely lost. For example, the completed image no longer lists a "Compression" or a "Resolution Unit" when you go into right click->properties for the image.